# How check difference between string and object string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 strings like this:

```
var a = 'Mario'; 
var b = '{title: 'Luigi', age: 38}';
```

and I want the new variable:

```
 c = 'Mario'; 
 d = {title: 'Luigi', age: 38};
```

How can I check the difference between `a` and `b` in the `if` condition?

I tryed with JSON.parse(); but it doens't work with the variable `a`.
The code I write is:

```
if( typeof(JSON.parse(x)) != 'object'){
  //then I want simply x that is a string
}else{
 //then I want JSON.parse(x) that is an object
}
```

Let's say that I have a database where there are saved all strings like 'a'. Now I want also save strings like 'b' at the same voice of database. In other words, in the database there are all strings, but some of them are strings like 'b' and I need to write something like `b.title`

I hope is much clear

Thanks!

Comment: What if the string is  `'false'` or `'null'`...? Then what do you expect as result?

Comment: *"I try with `JSON.parse`; but it doens't work with the variable `a`"*: it doesn't work with the variable `d` either. Neither is valid JSON. Please explain *why* you need it, as it is quite likely you need to change something at a step that occurs before getting into this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I edited the post and I hope that the question is more clear

Comment: Why not fix your database, and [normalise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was not clear to me but what I got is you want to differentiate between a string and string-object.
If so, use JSON.parse with try - catch block.

```
const a = 'Mario'; 
const b = "{'title': 'Luigi', 'age': '38'}";
const [c,d] = [a, b].map((e) => {
    try {
        return (JSON.parse(e))
    } catch (error) {
        return e
    }
})
```

Hope this helps you!